# Where to find resource bundle

Tags: jsp, jsf

A JSP i'm looking at has this tag at the top

```
<f:loadBundle basename="properties.marketing" var="marketID"/>
```

It's called several times using this :

```
<td width="33%" class="content"
<h:outputText value="#{marketID.ridehigh}"/>    

</td>
```

Question, where would I look to find properties.marketing from the first block of code.

Answer (score 0):

In the package `properties` in one of your source or resource folders or in a jar on your classpath, you should find a file `marketing.properties`. There also can be several files in the package called `properties` for different locales, e.g. `marketing_en.properties`, `marketing_de.properties`etc.